# Enable SSL on tomcat on Docker

Tags: docker, tomcat, ssl

I have local docker running up on my linux system. I'm trying to enable SSL on the docker container which runs tomcat. However I'm unable to get the SSL working. 
I get the below error when I try to access the REST endpoint deployed locally on docker.

```
Aug 13, 2018 5:36:25 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor process
INFO: Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
```

I have added the below code to the **server.xml**:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
           keystoreFile="/usr/java/default/lib/security/***.cert.p12" keystoreType="PKCS12" keystorePass="***" />
```

The same piece of code works fine when I try to deploy my java application on my local tomcat without docker.

Why is the same thing not working in tomcat on docker?

Comment: what's the error log?

Comment: Aug 13, 2018 5:36:25 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor process
INFO: Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.